# Firewalld: block outgoing connections on specific port

Tags: firewalld

I want to add a rule to `firewalld` in order to block any outgoing connections/traffic on port 9000 and leave the rest unchanged.
How to to that with `firewall-cmd` command?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From this post [Block outgoing connections on RHEL7/CentOS7 with firewalld?](https://serverfault.com/questions/618164/block-outgoing-connections-on-rhel7-centos7-with-firewalld)  :

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter OUTPUT 0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport=9000 -j DROP
firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter OUTPUT 1 -j ACCEPT
```

It should work after a running rules reload :

```
firewall-cmd --reload
```

Before this command this will not be applied.

Comment: How to undo this ?

Comment: @PratikPatil you could consult: https://serverfault.com/q/667731